# Node js API nginx webserver AWS load balancer

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I am currently having two nginx servers and an AWS load balancer in front of them. The static content is served with nginx. Can I use nodejs for the application logic and routing. I dont want to use nginx as a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two target groups, one for each application.

Then use the AWS Application Load Balance to manage your requests.

In the [Application Load Balance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html) you must configure the [listeners](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-update-rules.html) to forward the request to the correct target group.

[image: Application load balance]